# Watching for changes in Firebase using Node.js Script on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, firebase

I wrote the following script (`push_server.js`) to keep track of changes in my Firebase database and send push notifications when new values are added. It works well for the first few minutes, but then after maybe 5-10 minutes it stops noticing changes adds. Running the server locally it works fine, but when I push my code to Heroku it stops working after about 10-15 minutes. I upgraded to a [hobby dyno](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) so that it never sleeps, just in case, but it's still not working.

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");    
var ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com");

ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    send_push();
}, function(errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject);
});
```

How can I go about debugging this?

**Edit:** to make things even weirder, I received the notifications from my script on Heroku about 4 hours later....

I don't think this is a problem with either my script or the service I'm using for push notifications since it works perfectly on my local server.

Comment: how does your `send_push()` look like?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?